# There is a vector $y \in \mathbb{R^m}$ such that $A^Ty=0$ and $y^Tb \not=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let there be matrix $A_{m\times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R^m}$ , then either there exists a vector $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $Ax=b$ or there is a vector $y \in \mathbb{R^m}$ such that $A^Ty=0$ and $y^Tb \not=0$

I know that if rank of of $A$ is $n$, then we will have the $1$st case :there exists a vector $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ such that $Ax=b$; Now for the case rank $A <n$, how to approach? I did some: rank $A <n$ implies there is some $x \not=0 \in N(A)$ and we have $N(A)$ is orthogonal to $R(A^T)$. Thereafter, I need some help.

Comment: if rank of $A$ is $n$, still you can't guarantee $Ax=b$ has solution!!

if rank $A$ =m then $Ax=b$ always has solution

Comment: Are you familiar with linear programing and duality or Alternative theorems? If yes , I will solve this for you in less than three lines

Comment: I know some of LPP. I want to know the proof of the $1$st comment

Comment: Never mind, I'll write an elementary proof below

Answer (score 2):

Let $ Ax=b$ has no solution, thus $b \notin R(A).$  we know that $R^m = R(A)^{\perp} + R(A)$. So $$b=y+Ax$$  for some nonzero $y \in R(A)^{\perp}=N(A^T) $ and some $x\in R^n$. Hence ; $$A^Ty=0$$ and $$y^Tb=\|y\|^2+y^TAx = \|y\|^2 \neq 0$$
.

Comment: that's very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you try to solve the equation $Ax=b$. You can do it by Gaussian elimination. In the end, you get an equation of the type $A'x=b'$, whre $A'$ is something like$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1&*&*&*&*&*\\0&0&\alpha_2&*&*&*\\0&0&0&\alpha_3&*&*\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$with every $\alpha_k\neq0$. So, the system has a solution if and only if the last two coordinates of $b'$ are equal to $0$. Otherwise, take $y=(0,0,0,\beta_4,\beta_5)$, where $\beta_4$ and $\beta_5$ are the two last coordinates of $b'$.